# Subqueries in Laravel/Eloquent not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently working on a Lumen based application and I am stuck on an Eloquent/Laravel query. What I am currently working on is this:

```
$min = $filter['min_spending']*100;

$query = User::isCustomer()
    ->with("interests")
    ->leftJoin("points_history", "points_history.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->leftJoin("collections", "collections.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->select("users.*",
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM points_history
                      WHERE points_history.user_id = users.id
                      AND points_history.confirmed = true ) as total_points"),
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections
                      WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL 
                      AND refunded_at IS NULL
                      AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase"),
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(collections.price)) as current_purchase"))
            ->where("total_purchase", ">=", $min);

// other relevant code here

$query->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc');
```

However, when I try to get the result, I get this error:

```
{"error":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_purchase >=' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` left join `points_history` on `points_history`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `collections` on `collections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `role` = 2 and `total_purchase >=` = 200000 group by `users`.`id`)"}
```

The subqueries did not  seem to register which is causing the problem (?) My desired SQL Statement is this:

```
SELECT users . *, 
                    (SELECT 
                        SUM(amount)
                    FROM
                        points_history
                    WHERE
                        points_history.user_id = users.id
                            AND points_history.confirmed = true)  AS total_points, (SELECT 
                        SUM(price)
                    FROM
                        collections
                    WHERE
                        paid_at IS NOT NULL
                            AND refunded_at IS NULL
                            AND collections.user_id = users.id) AS total_purchase,  SUM(collections.price) AS current_purchase
                    from
                        users
                            left join
                        points_history ON points_history.user_id = users.id
                            left join
                        collections ON collections.user_id = users.id
                    where
                        users.deleted_at is null AND (SELECT 
                                SUM(price)
                            FROM
                                collections
                            WHERE
                                paid_at IS NOT NULL
                                    AND refunded_at IS NULL
                                    AND collections.user_id = users.id) >= 200000
GROUP BY users.id
```

where 200000 is $min. Could anyone help me pinpoint what the problem is in my query so I can figure out how to fix it?

Comment: You can try this with havingRaw()

Comment: Having() was my first go-to option but this system I am working on does not support having() because of its pagination function which I cannot omit nor change. My issue is the same as this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3105 except I cannot implement the suggested workaround because I am not supposed to touch the pagination function

Comment: Ok Trying to be mysql Strict False. On your Config/database.php. Then it should work.

Comment: It is already 'strict'    => false in my database.php

Comment: You could also use laravel's WhereRaw function to write your own conditions:

Comment: How can I use WhereRaw here? I  am not sure how

Comment: ->whereRaw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL  AND refunded_at IS NULL AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase", ">=", $min);

Comment: It gives me this error {"error":"Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::whereRaw() must be of the type array, string given"}

Comment: ->whereRaw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL AND refunded_at IS NULL AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase >= $min");

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
$min = $filter['min_spending']*100;

$query = User::isCustomer()
    ->with("interests")
    ->leftJoin("points_history", "points_history.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->leftJoin("collections", "collections.user_id", "=", "users.id")
    ->select("users.*",
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM points_history
                      WHERE points_history.user_id = users.id
                      AND points_history.confirmed = true ) as total_points"),
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections
                      WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL 
                      AND refunded_at IS NULL
                      AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase"),
            DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(collections.price)) as current_purchase"))
            ->where("total_purchase", '>=', $min);

// other relevant code here

$query->groupBy('users.id')->orderBy('users.created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me this error:

lumen.ERROR: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '>=' (T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL) in ...

so I added in ">=" in place of >= and I got the same error from before

Comment: >= should be in double qoutes ">="

Comment: whats your output now?

Comment: error: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_purchase' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` left join `points_history` on `points_history`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join `collections` on `collections`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and `role` = 2 and `total_purchase` >= 200200 group by `users`.`id`)"

Comment: is there any column named with  total_purchase  in your user table.if not try to add tablename.total_purchase in that line

Comment: total_purchase is from my second subquery:

 DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections
                      WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL 
                      AND refunded_at IS NULL
                      AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase")

but the system does not read it

Answer (score 0):

```
    ->where("total_purchase",">=", $min);
```

In the quick view, you did not put  "," in the last line

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED:**

Apparently, SELECT does not take multiple args but it accepts an array

```
->select(["users.*",
                    DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM points_history
                                WHERE points_history.user_id = users.id
                                AND points_history.confirmed = true ) as total_points"),
                    DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(price) FROM collections
                                WHERE paid_at IS NOT NULL 
                                AND refunded_at IS NULL
                                AND collections.user_id = users.id) as total_purchase"),
                    DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(collections.price)) as current_purchase")]
```

Also ended up changing the WHERE clause to

```
$query->whereRaw(DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM points_history
       WHERE points_history.user_id = users.id
       AND points_history.confirmed = true ) <= " . $max));
```

with a dot instead of a comma to concatenate to the query

Comment: Finally you are solve this prob. with whereRaw() :) . Cheers